# Use React-Resizable with Antd Grid's Row and Col

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using Antd's Row and Col ([Antd Grid](https://3x.ant.design/components/grid/)) for arranging different elements. I would like to use [react-resizable](https://github.com/STRML/react-resizable) along with Row and Col.

Tried using the following code and only shows the icon for drag at the bottom right. The reason is because with this grid system we use the span prop as span={12} for "Col". So how to resize in such case. TIA

```
<Row>
  <ResizableBox axis="x" draggableOpts={{}}>
    <Col span={12}>col-12</Col>
  </ResizableBox>
  <ResizableBox axis="x" draggableOpts={{}}>
    <Col span={12}>col-12</Col>
  </ResizableBox>
</Row>
```

Comment: Thanks. The main issue/question is how to manage to resize as I cant use height and width as that is managed by span prop for Col as shown here- https://codesandbox.io/s/9229wz40yo May be basic but little new to React.

Comment: I ended up converting all the Row and Col to div and used css "resize" property.